# How to code the MATLAB fix(X) function in C++?

Tags: c++, matlab

Basically I would like to recreate a MATLAB script in C++ code and I've noticed the script makes use of a `fix(X)` function which rounds each element of `X` to the nearest integer toward zero. Any advice on how a beginner should start would be highly appreciated!

For example:

```
X = [-1.9 -3.4; 1.6 2.5; -4.5 4.5]

X = 
    -1.9000  -3.4000
    1.6000   2.5000
    -4.5000  4.5000

Y = fix(X)

Y = 
    -1   -3
    1    2
    -4   4
```

Comment: Loop through your collection and cast each element as an `int`,  this will truncate the decimal part which is equivalent to rounding down towards zero.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming `X` is a `std::vector<double>`, you could do something like this:

```
std::transform(
    X.begin,
    X.end(),
    X.begin(),
    [](auto& elem) { elem = static_cast<int>(elem); }
);
```

Edit: As pointed out by @walnut, you need to keep in mind that the `int` may overflow. `std::trunc`, is a safer option.

For generic 2D/3D arrays, would not recommend using a `std::vector` of `std::vector`s, you should try the **[Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page)** library. It provides a similar API to Matlab.

Comment: This will only work as long as the floating point values are not out-of-range for `int`. Otherwise it causes undefined behavior. `std::trunc` does the correct thing also for larger values.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> nums{3.25, -4.5, 2.4, 9, -15.4, 267.4};
    std::for_each(nums.begin(), nums.end(), [](double &n){ std::cout << n << " "; });
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::for_each(nums.begin(), nums.end(), [](double &n){ std::cout << std::trunc(n) << " "; });

    return 0;
}
```